# How can import table from rdbms to to hive?

Tags: hive, sqoop

I am trying to import table from mysql to hive then i am getting following error.

can you please provide the solution for this.

bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://202.63.155.22:3306/demo --username careuser --P --table caremanager --hive-import --verbose -m 1

```
3/12/30 02:42:05 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: 
  Column createddate had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive
13/12/30 02:42:05 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job:
  java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hive": error=2, No such file or directory
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually sqoop is trying to access hive for creating hive table but cant execute it. Is hive installed on your machine and is Hive home is set in PATH environment variable.Please verify it.Hope these will solve your problem.